# angular ui bootstrap alert is not closing on clicking x

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, alert

I want to use single uib-alert, not array of alerts.

this is my controller code:

```
$scope.projCompleteSuccess=true;
$scope.closeCompleteProjectAlert=function(){
        $scope.projCompleteSuccess=false;              
    }
```

html:

```
<uib-alert  type="danger" close="closeCompleteProjectAlert()" 
     ng-if="projCompleteSuccess">        
</uib-alert>
```

Comment: It works for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/UIrictfC5kKDhT8QVJfX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use follow the document from [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
<div uib-alert type="danger" close="closeCompleteProjectAlert()" 
     ng-if="projCompleteSuccess"></div>
```

See the [Pluker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UIrictfC5kKDhT8QVJfX?p=preview)